# Unit Testing Inherited WPF UserControl

Tags: wpf, unit-testing

I have inherited `ScrollViewer`, call it `MyScrollViewer`. In the constructor of `MyScrollViewer`, I subscribe to `ScrollViewer.GotFocus += OnGotFocus` and do some processing.

In my unit tests, I create a new `MyScrollViewer`. How can I raise the GotFocus event manually?

Apologies for missing code, I'm not sure if I am allowed to paste this code online.

Thanks!
Ken